# Is there a var.contains - C#

Tags: c#

I have a question about the following code:

```
private void Filter (object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    List<Animal> animalList = new List<Animal>();

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_editText.Text)) 
    {
        foreach (string str in _animalList)
        {                
            if (str.Contains(_editText.Text))
            {
                animalList.Add (str);
            }
        }
    }
    _listView.Adapter = new AnimalAdapter(this, _animalList = animalList);
}
```

The `Animal` class:

```
public class Animal
{
    private readonly int _intKey;

    public int AnimalNumber { get; private set; }
    public int StableNumber { get; private set; }
    public int LactoseNumber { get; private set; }

    public Animal ( int intKey, int animalNumber, int stableNumber, int lactoseNumber )
    {
        _intKey = intKey;
        AnimalNumber = animalNumber;
        StableNumber = stableNumber;
        LactoseNumber = lactoseNumber;
    }

    public override string ToString ()
    {
        return "Number: " + AnimalNumber + "\nGroup: " + StableNumber + "\nLactation: " + LactoseNumber;
    }
}
```

Declaration of  `_animalList`:

```
private List<Animal> _animalList;
```

i need to check if the `_animalList` Contains the input of the `_editText.Text`.
But _animalList isn't a `string` so i need to use a `var`.

Is there something like a `var.Contains` or do i have to use something else?

Comment: Could you please post the definition of `Animal` class? Thanks

Comment: I will put the animal class in de question

Comment: You don't need to use `var` which is just a replacement for the actual type (you only really need it for anonymous types). You can use `Animal`. But what property of `Animal` do you want to compare with the input text?

Comment: @TimSchmelter i need to know if str in contains the input of my editText. _editText is a Textbox

Comment: your _animalList is a collection of whatever type. You should iterate in collection to accomplish this. Also, give us the definition of `_animalList`. Is it the same as the definition of `animalList`?

Comment: @user123456789987654321: but `_animalList` is a `List<Animal>` so `str` actually isn't a `string` but an `Animal`. So just use the property you want. What property does `_editText.Text` map to?

Comment: OP, it is very unclear what you mean by _"to check if the _animalList Contains the input of the _editText.Text"_. Define "contains". What exactly do you want to happen when with what input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) method is available for `string` type. You will need to cast your object to `string`.

A/c to your class definition you should do like:

```
foreach (Animal str in _animalList)
{                
    if (str.ToString().Contains(_editText.Text)) //using user defined "ToString()"
    {
        animalList.Add (str);
    }
}
```

You can also check individual properties:

```
foreach (Animal str in _animalList)
{                
    if (str.AnimalNumber.ToString().Contains(_editText.Text)) //if "AnimalNumber" is like "_editText.Text"
    {
        animalList.Add (str);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear that OP wants to compare the input text with the string which is returned from `ToString`. The answer also doesn't explain why OP doesn't need `var` but can use `Animal` instead of `string`.

Comment: Alex: There was an initial downvote putting it to -1 and now seem to be two (with higher rep you can see the actual number of up and down votes).

Comment: @TimSchmelter I thinks he wants to match with all the properties of the object. Thats what I understood.

Comment: @Shaharyar You are right with that awnser. You nailed it thanks for your help and i will mark it as an Awnser as soon as possible

Comment: @user123456789987654321 Your question was very unclear. When you ask a question, define each and every thing which relates to the question

Comment: Um.. is it correct tough? `Contains` on a string will look for substrings inside the string. What you want is equality here, per your vague requirements.

Comment: @tne Where did you find equality in the given code? Its all about similarity.

Comment: @Shaharyar i will keep your advise in mind for future questions. Thanks for you help

Comment: @Shaharyar: You're right, OP didn't specify what the `_editText.Text` is or what it looks like.

Comment: @Shaharyar: if you'd edit your answer i could undo my downvote. You could for example add another approach like checking the properties  instead of `ToString`. Then it also might be helpful for futuree visitors. Otherwise i'm afraid that people will try to use `ToString().Contains` even if `ToString` is not overridden.

Comment: @TimSchmelter A bit more explanation added.

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputText = _editText.Text;
int enteredNumber;

// you should make sure that the inputText is always an int
var isInt = int.TryParse(inputText, out enteredNumber);
//for example, if you are going to find by AnimalNumber, which is an int, you can use this. .
if (isInt){
    foreach (var animal in _animalList){
        var animalNumber = animal.AnimalNumber;
        if (animalNumber == enteredNumber)
        {
            animalList.Add(animal);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit** (LINQ alternative):

```
        if (isInt){
            animalList.AddRange(from animal in _animalList
                let animalNumber = animal.AnimalNumber
                where animalNumber == enteredNumber
                select animal);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to filter using `ToString`, it would be better to use the real property values. For example:

```
var number = Convert.ToInt32(_editText.Text); 
var filteredList = _animalList
       .Where(x => x.AnimalNumber == number || 
                   x.StableNumber == number || 
                   x.LactoseNumber == number)
       .ToList();
```

Otherwise, user could type "Number" and since your `ToString` override contains that string, all of the items in the list would match positively.

(I didn't include any validation or error checking in the code above, so you should consider those as well).

Answer (score 0):

```
_animalList.Select(a => a.ToString()).Contains(_editText.Text)
```

This expression returns `true` if the output of the `ToString` method of any animal object equals `_editText.Text`.

```
_animalList.Select(a => a.ToString()).Any(str => str.Contains(_editText.Text))
```

This expression returns `true` if the output of the `ToString` method of any animal object contains `_editText.Text` (as a substring). This is equivalent to Shaharyar's answer.

```
var animalList = _animalList.Where(a => a.ToString().Equals(_editText.Text)).ToList();
var animalList = _animalList.Where(a => a.ToString().Contains(_editText.Text)).ToList();
```

These statements filter the input list directly.

Comment: @TP Yes this is the solution you are looking for. Remember when you use a foreach you can mostly rewrite it to a LINQ query